# SQLDUMPER.EXE spontaneously opening

Tags: sql-server

I have a very annoying problem, where SQLDUMPER.EXE spontaneously opens in the form of a command line and then closes after less than a second. This happens maybe twice per hour. It's not a huge problem but it's an annoyance as it takes the focus away from whatever window I'm working in.

Does anybody know why this happens or how to stop it?

---

## Update

I'm getting the following entry in the Windows Event Log

> Fault bucket , type 0
>
> Event Name: SQLException64
>
> Response: Not available
>
> Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature:
>
> P1: sqlservr.exe
>
> P2: 0.0.0.0
>
> P3: 0000000000000000
>
> P4: sqlmin.dll
>
> P5: 2015.130.1722.0
>
> P6: 0000000057E9D225
>
> P7: -1073741819
>
> P8: 0000000000174642
>
> P9: 000000009411A626
>
> P10:
>
> Attached files: [location of dump files on my computer]
>
> These files may be available here:
>
> Analysis symbol:
>
> Rechecking for solution: 0
>
> Report ID: 6dc85d78-dfcd-11e6-a01b-f81654a7cd02
>
> Report Status: 262144
>
> Hashed bucket:

I checked out the dump that SQLDUMPER is creating. The log file contains the following text:

> 2017-01-21 12:33:29.23 spid37s     Open of fault log AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\ProjectsV13\..\log\exception.log failed.
>
> 2017-01-21 12:33:29.23 spid37s     ***Stack Dump being sent to AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\ProjectsV13\SQLDump0849.txt
>
> 2017-01-21 12:33:29.23 spid37s     SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 37 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of scheduled backup task.

Comment: I assume that the machine you're on has SQL Server installed. What version?

Comment: @BenThul sorry missed this! 2016 developer edition.

Comment: Okay. I don't remember what my motivation was for asking what version you were running. :) Are there dump files in your error log directory? To be clear, this shouldn't be a normal occurrence. Dump files are generally because something bad happened with the SQL executable (though you can trigger your own dump through extended events).

Comment: @BenThul updated the question.

Comment: May have found an answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0c486ed7-9fdb-45f0-9fcd-342eadbb0476/sqlserverexe-crashing?forum=ssdt). Will report back...